# Why will Smarty remove Support for using PHP Functions as Modifiers?

Tags: php, smarty

After switching to PHP 8.2 and Smarty 4.3,
I get a lot of deprecation warnings like

PHP Deprecated:  Using php-function "substr" as a modifier is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Use Smarty::registerPlugin to explicitly register a custom modifier

This message comes for substr, rand, mt_rand, json_encode and others.

Why where the PHP Functions removed, and is there an easy way to get the function back from the Smarty Repository or does every user of Smarty has to write these functions on his own?

They where really useful ...

Comment: The functions haven't been removed, "_support for using PHP functions as modifiers_" [has been removed](https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/issues/813) in Smarty. You probably need to create/use Plugins to continue using your functionality

Comment: @brombeer Of course they did not remove the PHP Functions but the support. Thanks for the link, the decision seemed to be quite controversial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be solved in a very simple way, you just need to do this:

```
$smarty->registerPlugin("modifier", "substr", "substr");
$smarty->registerPlugin("modifier", "rand", "rand");
$smarty->registerPlugin("modifier", "json_encode", "json_encode");
```

And the same for every modifier you need. The other option is to replace the modifier with the use of the function, so this:

```
{$var|substr:0:10}
```

To this:

```
{substr($var,0,10)}
```